# Not able to run WebdriverIO script on Edge

Tags: node.js, microsoft-edge, webdriver-io

not able to run webdriverio automation script on edge.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofj5K.png)

Comment: Can you please inform us, which version of the MS Edge browser you are using for making this test? If possible then try to provide the sample code and steps to reproduce the issue. Try to provide detailed information about the issue. We will try to check and test the issue. Only error message will not give an idea about the cause for the issue.

Comment: Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0 and Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763 is my edge version

Answer (score 0):

when i try installing edge using npm command, i get below error:

WebdriverIOScripts> npm install edgedriver
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.5: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.3: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.1.14: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js

> edgedriver@4.17134.1 install D:\Argus\WebdriverIOScripts\node_modules\edgedriver
>   node install.js

downloadUrl:
invalid config loglevel="notice"
NOTE: Cannot find Microsoft WebDriver for the current OS: win32 x64 10.0.17763
npm WARN chai-webdriverio@1.0.0 requires a peer of chai@~4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webdriverioscripts@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- edgedriver@4.17134.1
  updated 1 package and audited 3451 packages in 7.145s

35 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 9 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install the Edge web driver for the MS Edge legacy browser then you could refer to the steps below.

Microsoft WebDriver for Microsoft Edge Legacy versions 18 and 19 is a Windows Feature on Demand which ensures that it’s always up to date automatically and enables some new ways to get Microsoft WebDriver.

Users need to enable the Developer mode first.

> Go to Settings > Update and Security > For Developer and then select
>   “Developer mode”.

To install the web driver run the following command in an elevated command prompt (Run the command prompt as an administrator).

> DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability
>   /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0

The Web driver will get installed on the location below.

> C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe

References:

1. [WebDriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)
2. [Automation Protocols](https://webdriver.io/docs/automationProtocols.html)

Let us know, whether the above steps are helpful to you to install the web driver or not.